# How to work with phases in Activity diagram for Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013, uml

I'm trying to understand the "Phase", and in my humble mind i would like to add yet another Phase to the swim-lane. Though there isn't any "Insert Phase..." when I right click or other.

Anyone that can give me any ideas or links to videos about to do this?

Comment: please post some images, it would be easier for me to understand the problem and try to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Click "Cross-functional flowchart" from the ribbon, choose "Separator" and then drop it on the swim lanes.